# how to fetch firebase particular record

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I am working on firebase project with ionic 3 and angular 4, where I stored service info within a table, now my requirement is to show particular service data on my application which is stored in a table. Here is my firebase real time database snapshot

[image]

I can fetch all services with from firebase real time database using. Now i want to display particular service detail on my service detail page. I also wanted to edit and delete that services from service-list page.But i am not able to access the value directly as firebase real time database have its own structure to store value, it generate node id for each record e.g "-KzSHVrbZNJutXFYJDsX".
I wanted to fetch single record value which i can display on my detail page but i don't know how to access the value of that node id or value inside it.

service_list.ts

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private fdb: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.fdb.list("/services/").valueChanges().subscribe(_data => {
      this.items = _data;
     console.log(this.items);
    });
```

service_list.html

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of items">
<ion-item  (click)="viewItem(item)">
    <!-- <img src="{{item.icon}}"> -->
    <p>{{item.Service_name}}</p>
    <p><strong>{{item.Service_type}}</strong></p>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button (click)="removeService(item)" class="button">Delete</button>
<button ion-button (click)="updateService(item.S_ID,item.Service_name)" class="button">Edit</button>
```

Comment: so what exactly is the question here?